# Mustache.js - How do you hook up events?

Tags: mustache

I'm considering using Mustache.js for a small project I'm working on.... The one thing that I haven't seen an answer for is - Which is the best way to go about hooking up events?

I was thing of creating a tree menu with mustache but I can't think which would be the best or cleanest way to hook up events to each node?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mustache is a template engine; it's concerned only with markup, not behavior. To wire in events you should use the same best practices with HTML generated by hand or with any other templating engine--that is, by attaching events to nodes using addEventListener or with your library of choice's (jQuery/Prototype/Dojo/YUI) preferred methods. Just give your nodes appropriate ids and classnames in your templates and do the rest as usual.

Comment: I guessed that the frameworks would be the most practical.. but I was looking for maybe a more elegant built in way of doing it without the use of say jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, Mustache.js doesn't have any built-in facilities for behavior, but fortunately you have your pick of the litter for frameworks and I'm sure you can find one that meets your standard of elegance.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. Yep I will use jQuery to hookup events once the template is rendered. Thanks again