# How can I implement a HTML Select EventListener for a Mustache.js template using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache, event-listener

I am currently working on a website with Node.js (v8.9.4) in Visual Studio Code. The website uses a Mustache.js template with two HTML Select elements. The first one is automatically filled with different selectable Option elements called "experiment". The second Select element should be dynamically filled with Options elements representing the patient data in dependence which experiment was selected before (also when the http server response has already written the html file and its underlying mustache template).

Is my intension even possible and if yes how can I implement it?

I have tried some things (with a button as an example) but it didn't work.

My research:

[How do I add a simple onclick on a JavaScript mustache template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391955/how-do-i-add-a-simple-onclick-on-a-javascript-mustache-template)

[Executing function on a click event in a mustache template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419243/executing-function-on-a-click-event-in-a-mustache-template)

My mustache template:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<ul>{{#messages}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/messages}}</ul>
<select>{{#experimentOptions}}<option>{{.}}</option>{{/experimentOptions}} </select>
<select>{{#patientOptions}}<option>{{.}}</option>{{/patientOptions}</select>
<button onClick={{clickFunction}}>Click Me</button>
```

My model:

```
var model = 
{
    title: 'My Website', 
    experimentOptions: experiments,
    patientOptions: patients,
    clickFunction: function()
    {
        console.log("Button was pressed.");
    }
}
```

Result:

The message "Button was pressed" is printed two times on the console when the html file is written. But when I click my button nothing happens.

The same counts if I change my template to:

```
<button>{{clickFunction}}</button>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You would do this the exact same way as you would with a static website that isn't served by node (express?). Add a client-side JS script, include it in your html document (using `<script>`), and set up the event listener in the script. As far as I can see, node/mustache are largely irrelevant to the question, which is far simpler than you realize.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mustache.js - How do you hook up events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101586/mustache-js-how-do-you-hook-up-events)

Comment: I created in my javascript project folder a client-side JS script called eventHandler.js and wrote following code: document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("Button was clicked.");
}). Additionally I update the mustache template to: <script src="javascript/eventHandling.js"></script>. But in the end nothing happened as well. Am I referencing the JS script in the wrong way or do I miss something?

Comment: I'm not seeing `btn1` anywhere in your template.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't a full copy paste: <button id="btn1">Click me</button>

Comment: What you tried is supposed to work in principle, but there could be all kinds issues. The two usual ones: path to script is wrong, listener is assigned before element exists. Show us the generated HTML, make sure the script is linked properly, and make sure its tag is in `<body>`, after the `<button>`: http://jsbin.com/jehepaniru/edit?html,output

Comment: So here is my generated HTML: <body>
    <h1>My Website</h1>
    <select><option>experiment1</option><option>experiment2</option></select>
    <select><option>ID12_V0_R1_UL</option><option>ID13_V0_R2_UL</option></select>
    <button id="btn1">Click me</button>
    <script src="../javascript/eventHandling.js"></script>
</body>

Comment: My project folder structure consist of a javascript, mustache, css and resources folder. The eventHandler.js is in the JS folder. I am starting the whole thing from main.js. The template is in the mustache folder. I have tried several path versions. The one above, javascript/eventHandling.js and just eventHandling.js with the same result. The alert message wasn't printed.

Comment: I have to ask you a stupid question (just for the record): In your first comment you mentioned to include my JS script in the html document. I assumed you meant the one which is created through mustache.toHtml(template, model)? So by inclusion you meant the declaration in the mustache template?

Comment: Can you point me to the tutorial you're using? And no, I meant to do the  exact same thing you would do with a static HTML file and a static JS file.

Comment: I haven't found a well-structured, well-explained tutorial yet. Which is the reason for my obvious lack of knowledge. If you could recommend me one I would be grateful. In the meantime I will refactor my code / structure according to your input.